# Why are some variables not defined?

Tags: python, dictionary

This is what I have to do:

Look up and print the student GPA

Add a new student to the class

Change the GPA of a student

Change the expected grade of a student

Print the data of all the students in a tabular format

Quit the program

```
    import student
    import pickle

    lookup = 1
    change = 2
    add = 3
    delete = 4
    QUIT = 0
    FILENAME = 'student.dat'

    def main():

        students_info = load_students()
        choice = 0
        load_students()
        #add(students_info)
        change_grade(students_info)
        change_GPA(students_info)
        #get_menu_choice()
        look_up(students_info)
        while choice != QUIT:
            choice = get_menu_choice()
            if choice == lookup:
                look_up(students_info)
            elif choice == add:
                add(students_info)
            elif choice == change:
                change(students_info)
            elif choice == delete:
                delete(students_info)
        save_students(students_info)


    def load_students():
        try:
            input_file = open(FILENAME, 'rb')
            students_dict = pickle.load(input_file)
            input_file.close()
        except IOError:
            students_dict = {}
        print(students_dict)
        return students_dict

    def get_menu_choice():
        print()
        print('Menu')
        print("-------------------")
        print('1. Look up ID')
        print('2.....')
        choice = int(input("Enter your choice:"))

        return choice

    def look_up(students_info):
        ID = input('Enter ID:')
        print(student_info.get(ID, "Not found!"))
    ##    try:
    ##        print(students_info[ID])
    ##    except KeyError:
    ##        print("Not found!")

    def change_GPA(students_info):
        ID = input("ID:")
        if ID in students_info:
            GPA= float(input("New GPA:"))
            students=student.Student(ID,GPA,grade,work)
            students_info[ID] = students
            print ("This",students_info[ID])
        else:
            print("Not found!")
    def change_grade(students_info):
        ID = input("ID:")
        if ID in students_info:
            New_grade = input("Enter new grade:")
            students=student.Student(ID,GPA,grade,work)
            students_info[ID] = students
            #new_grade = students_info[name]
        else:
            print("Not found!")

    def add(students_info):
        name = input("Enter the student name:")
        ID= input("Enter student's ID:")
        GPA= float(input("Enter GPA:"))
        grade= input("Enter student's expected grade:")
        work = input("Does the student work part time or full time?")
        students=student.Student(name,ID,GPA,grade,work)
        print(students_info['ID'])
    def save_students(students_info):
        output_file = open(FILENAME, 'wb')
        pickle.dump(students_info, output_file)
        output_file.close()
    main()
```

Whenever I tried to change the GPA or grade it's not defined. How could I change one value from the dictionary studens_info?

Comment: You should define the question first..

Comment: Are you getting an error message at a specific line of code? Where are the variables `grade` and `work` assigned for lines `students=student.Student(ID,GPA,grade,work)`?

Comment: @gus42 Yes! That's the problem I'm having.

Comment: And so the answer to your question is: the variables are not defined because you haven't assigned a value to them. Assign the correct values and one of your problems is gone.

Answer (score 0):

As gus42 has commented, the errors you are getting are from the lines:

```
students=student.Student(ID,GPA,grade,work)
```

You've not defined `grade` or `work` in either of the places you do this (nor GPA in `change_grade`), so it should not be surprising that you're getting an error.

I think there are two ways to fix the issue:

The simplest way is to change your logic from creating a new `Student` object to modifying the one that already exists. I don't know exactly what the attribute names are in your `Student` class, but here's a reasonable guess at a solution:

```
def change_GPA(students_info):
    ID = input("ID:")
    if ID in students_info:
        GPA= float(input("New GPA:"))
        students_info[ID].GPA = GPA  # assign new GPA to old student object

    else:
        print("Not found!")

def change_grade(students_info):
    ID = input("ID:")
    if ID in students_info:
        grade = input("Enter new grade:")
        students_info[ID].grade = grade  # assign new grade to existing student object
    else:
        print("Not found!")
```

The other option is to replace the existing `Student` object with a new one with some different values. This is close to what your current code, but it only really makes sense if your `Student` objects are immutable (perhaps because you made the type with `namedtuple`?). To make it work (where your current code does not), you'll have to load the old values from the old `Student` object before making the new object:

```
def change_GPA(students_info):
    ID = input("ID:")
    if ID in students_info:
        new_GPA = float(input("New GPA:"))
        old_grade = students_info[ID].grade  # load old values
        old_work = students_info[ID].work
        new_student = students.Student(ID, new_GPA, old_grade, old_work)
        students_info[ID] = new_student  # replace the old student with a new object
    else:
        print("Not found!")

def change_grade(students_info):
    ID = input("ID:")
    if ID in students_info:
        new_grade = input("Enter new grade:")
        old_GPA = students_info[ID].GPA
        old_work = students_info[ID].work
        new_student = students.Student(ID, old_GPA, new_grade, old_work)
        students_info[ID] = new_student
    else:
        print("Not found!")
```

Comment: I tried this but it's still giving me the old output GPA and grade. Any suggestions?

Comment: @lastdancestop: as I mentioned in the answer, I don't actually know how your `Student` class works. You'll need to adapt my code to the actual attributes of that class (rather than relying on my guesses being correct).

Comment: Yes! I changed it to my attributes for example grade = grade_course but it's giving the error of 'Student' object has no attribute 'grade_course'